# Increasing the efficiency of a Differential Pulley

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, data-analysis

The efficiency of a Weston differential pulley block can be determined using the following equation.

$$E=\frac{FR \ (100)}{MR}$$

As this is the case, in order to increase the efficiency the biggest possible force ratio value is needed and the smallest possible movement ratio is needed.
\begin{align}
FR & = \frac{Ouput \ Force}{Input \ Force} \\
 & = \frac{2}{1-\frac{r_{output}}{r_{input}}}
\end{align}

$$MR = \frac{Input \ Movement}{Output \ Movement}$$

To work out the radius of a cog the equation is $r = chain \ pitch \ (\frac{1}{2sin(\frac{\pi}{teeth})})$ but as the chain pitch is constant in a Weston differentail pulley block, we can just use the number of teeth on each cog as the values for $r_{output}$ and $r_{input}$.

With this is mind the I decided to try it out in this simple set of factors.

> Input Cog: 25 teeth
>   Output Cog: 20 teeth
>   Chain Pitch: 20mm
>   Input Cog Pulled: 1m

\begin{align}
Revolutions & = \frac{1000}{20(25)} \\
& = 2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Output \ Movement & = 2(20)(20) \\
& = 0.8m
\end{align}

$$MR = 1.25$$

\begin{align}
FR & = \frac{2}{1-\frac{20}{25}} \\
& = 10
\end{align}

So the efficiency would be $\frac{10(100)}{1.25}$ which is $800\%$.

Am I correct in assuming I went wrong somewhere as the efficiency is so high? And where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note: I put this under solution verification and it seems to automatically of changed to proof verificaion

Comment: It seems you are using parentheses instead of a multiplication sign, and that is pretty confusing.

Comment: @Lovsovs I apologise, I've just been taught to do it that way over the years.

Comment: No problem, it can just look like what's being multiplied with is the input of a function, e.g., you would read $f(x)$ as "$f$ is a function of $x$" and not "$f$ multiplied with $x$". W.r.t. the question, there are a lot of engineering terms at play here, very few of which I know. However, I would be skeptical if anything denoted "efficiency" could go above $1$ (your result is $8$), per definition. That is at least not the case in physics.

Comment: @Lovsovs Ah okay and thanks for the response. I was working under the same assumption that efficiency cannot be above 1, hence the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes your force ratio and movement ratio are both wrong.

Firstly the equation for force ratio is actually the equation for movement ratio.  And the little r's are NOT the number of teeth on the cogs, they are the RADII of those cogs.  The equation is derived from effort movement / force movement which is 2R / (R-r) after the pi's are cancelled out, and can be rearranged into the form you give it in above, but I repeat it is the movement ratio not the force ratio.

Force ratio is Load Force divided by Effort Force.

So quite a lot to think about!